# How do you save an array to a PNG image in RAM using Julia?

Tags: image, julia

Saving an image to a PNG file is not a problem, the following code works fine (using Julia 1.5, FileIO 1.4.1 and ImageIO 0.3.0):

```
using FileIO

image = rand(UInt8, 200, 150, 3)
save("test.png", image)
```

However, I cannot find how to save the PNG image to a RAM buffer instead. I tried this:

```
io = IOBuffer()
save(Stream(format"PNG", io), image)
data = take!(io)
```

There's no error, but the resulting data is much too small: just 809 bytes (instead of about 90kB for the test.png file).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code worked well on my system, but I had to install (i.e. `Pkg.add`) the `ImageMagick` package in order to avoid errors when saving to a stream.

Comment: On my system (Julia 1.5 Windows) this is saving 3 separate B&W files so does not seem to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your I/O code is correct but you are incorrectly generating the random image.

It should be:

```
using Images
image = [RGB(rand(N0f8,3)...) for x in 1:200, y in 1:150]
```

Now both the `png` file and buffer will have the same size in bytes (since png is compressed the exact number will vary with each randomized run):

```
julia> save(Stream(format"PNG", io), image)
90415
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! :) Why does `save()` accept to save my image to disk but not to stream, while it accepts your image to both? Should I file a bug?

Comment: I do not like the way `save()` works in your example - it should rather throw an error - looks like a bug to me.